# How vulnerable is the this dynamically created sql?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection

I can find so much information on the web about the proper and safe way of dynamically creating parameterized queries. However such websites only talk about parameterization of the where clause.

Well, what about the other clauses of a sql statement? See the following:

```
       string sql = string.Format(@"                
            SELECT MIN(TableName) as TableName, {0}
            FROM
            (
              SELECT 'Table A' as TableName, {0}
              FROM {1}
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'Table B' as TableName, {0}
              FROM {2}
            ) tmp
            GROUP BY {0}
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1", columnList, tableA, tableB);
```

I'm constructing a statement whereby the following has been parameterized:

1. The items in the select clause
2. The tablename in the from clause

Question:
How vulnerable is this to sql injection that can cause some damage?

I can't think of anyway a malicious hacker could inject sql that will result in properly formed, executable sql. But then again, I'm not an sql expert.

Comment: Any time any part of the query comes from an untrusted source, it's vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. For instance, if you have some line of code above `tableA = someBool ? "foo" : "bar";` then there's no risk because it's going to be either foo or bar. But if you're getting the value of `tableA` from some form submission or some other external source you don't have control of, then you're at risk. Same goes for the other variables used in the query.

Comment: use parameterized query, that is recommended approach

Comment: @EhsanSajjad sql parameters can't be used for table and column names.

Comment: @itsme86 From what I can determine, the only risk is injection of code that will cause the sql to fail. Am I wrong?

Comment: other comments are showing up, but just to play devil's advocate, let's say someone could get your code to execute with the value of `columnList = "null from myTable; drop table myTable; ..."` and it doesn't matter if the rest of the sql is garbage or not. If the engine is told to run that until it fails, you MIGHT end up with a problem.

Comment: you are correct that the sql will fail, but that's not the point. Depending on how the query gets parsed and executed, it only has to execute JUST ENOUGH to do damage, and then it doesn't matter if the rest blows up, or even how it blows up, because the damage is done...

Comment: @SlimsGhost I'm almost afraid to ask this because it sounds to be a stupid question, but here we go: It's possible to inject into the select list of my code snippet some sql  that will execute?

Comment: That is the correction question, not a stupid one! :)  And the answer is "maybe".  You really have to determine for yourself how the variables get their values assigned before being passed in to your "query builder". If those values can be manipulated by end-users or even other developers, you should protect yourself by sanitizing the inputs.  And if you're going to sanitize inputs, parameterized queries are the way to do it.  It all depends on your specific situation and what values COULD end up going into the query.

Comment: Based on your code, I am guessing `columnList` is a comma separated string, so say I am injecting into your code, instead of giving just a list of columns I do this - `Column1,Column2 FROM TableA; DROP TABLE TableB;--` Now your original select is valid, and the drop table is also valid, and the rest of your query, depending on how it handles the line breaks, is commented out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Andrew states in his answer, if the parameter(s) are not impacted by any user input, or otherwise gets validated/cleaned it should be fine.

To answer your point about a possible properly formed SQL statement... The only areas that draw concern are potential escaped characters (such as a semi-colon, that can technically be placed anywhere in the command block) and/or something well-formed at the `{1}` and `{2}` sections of the statement.

Comment: I think {0} is just as vulnerable. `* FROM TableA; DROP TABLE TableB; SELECT *`

Comment: @Andrew I consider that form of attack / exploit as an escape character (semi-colon); which, technically, can go anywhere in the command block. I'll update my answer, as your comment is correct also.

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on where `columnList`, `tableA`, and `tableB` come from. If they come from your code, with no user input, then it's pretty safe. If the user specifies the table names, you have to be ready to meet [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327).

In my company's main c# application we use something similar for declaring columns, but the columns in the SQL tables are defined in a class for that table, so we can build select, add, update and create table strings from that class. Never does the user get to define those columns.